# p5.js: how can I limit keyPressed to sending just 1 output?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to prevent players from pressing both left and right keys at the same time, since doing so will change both "isLeft" and "isRight" to true. I've tried the code below but it makes the controls really stiff, for example, if you were to let go of "D" too late before pushing "A", it will register "D" being released but would not register "A" being pressed (since A is pressed when "isRight" is true. Sorry if this analogy is too confusing...

I'm looking for a way to take input from pressing "A", and if "D" is still pressed after "A" is released, immediately take input from "D".

Thanks in advance!

```
function keyPressed()
{
if ((key == 'A' || keyCode == 37) && !isRight)
    {
        isLeft = true;
    }
        
else if ((key == 'D' || keyCode == 39) && !isLeft)
    {
        isRight = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to interpret left vs right when both keys are pressed is to listen for `keyPressed` and `keyReleased`. On `keyReleased` we can also check and see if the alternate key is already down. This approach allows the code to immeditally switch to the other key when both are down and one is released

```js
var isLeft = false;
var isRight = false;

function setup(){
    frameRate(10);
}

function keyPressed(){
  if ((key == 'A' || keyCode == 37) && !isRight){
    isLeft = true;
    } else if ((key == 'D' || keyCode == 39) && !isLeft) {
        isRight = true;
    }
}

function keyReleased(){
  if ((key == 'A' || keyCode == 37)){
    isLeft = false;
    if ((keyIsDown(16) && keyIsDown(68)) || keyIsDown(39)){
      isRight = true;
    }
  }      
  else if ((key == 'D' || keyCode == 39)){
    isRight = false;
    if ((keyIsDown(16) && keyIsDown(65))|| keyIsDown(37)){
      isLeft = true;
    }
  }
}

function draw(){
  console.log( " isLeft: "+isLeft + " isRight: " + isRight);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hello charlie, thank you for your help on this question. do you mind helping me with another question regarding p5.js? i'm kind of desperate... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68564759/p5js-javascript-got-an-error-trying-to-pass-in-2-objects-into-a-function-unca

Answer (score 0):

The keyIsDown detects if a key is being pressed. I'm not sure if it works for all characters, but it works for the arrow keys. If you add !keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW), then it sees if the Right arrow is down. If it's down, then the if isn't true, if it's false the if is true it's being run.

Tell me if this doesn't work.

```
  function keyPressed()
{
if ((key == 'A' || keyCode == 37) && !isRight&&!keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW))
    {
        isLeft = true;
    }
        
else if ((key == 'D' || keyCode == 39) && !isLeft!keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW))
    {
        isRight = true;
    }
}
```